# How to return only one instance of each, from the entire loop

Tags: loop, filters, taxonomy

I´m adding a filter function in a taxonomy archive template.

The intention is to add URLs for filtering in a sidebar, and i want it to return a set of ACFs like zipcode etc... (postnr in this example is the same as zipcode)

The first "problem" is that so far it returns the requested output but once for each post like this

- 7011 Trondheim
- 7048 Trondheim
- 7022 Trondheim
- 7011 Trondheim
- 7011 Trondheim
- 7048 Trondheim
- 7022 Trondheim

All good, but I want it to return each option only once. (for extra spice we can have a count behind each like this: But not nessesarry.

- 7011 Trondheim (3)
- 7048 Trondheim (2)
- 7022 Trondheim (2)

The second problem is that it will only take in consideration the post in the loop that falls between the pagination "borders"

How can we get this to concider ALL posts within the current taxonomy?

```
<?php if( have_posts()): the_post()  ?>
 <h3>Filter etter postnr:</h3>
 <ul>
  <?php while ( have_posts()): the_post();
        //global $post; 
        $postnr = '';?>
  <li>
   <a href="?postnr=<?php the_field("postnummer")?>"><?php the_field("postnummer");?>
  - <?php the_field("poststed"); ?></a>
   </li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Store the id or something that uniquely identifies each one in an array as you're looping through.  At the beginning of the loop, check to see if the id is in the array, which means it's already been displayed.  If it has, skip it (continue).  This is a php question that happens in the context of WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a loop before you get to your sidebar loop to initiate your unique values. You could run the same loop twice, with [`rewind_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) between the two loops ( so you get your original loop, starting from index 0 ).

In your first loop, loop through and add all your values to an array so that the array looks something like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => '7011 Trondheim',
    [1] => '7048 Trondheim',
    [2] => '7022 Trondheim',
    [3] => '7011 Trondheim',
    [4] => '7011 Trondheim',
    [5] => '7048 Trondheim',
    [6] => '7022 Trondheim'
)
```

Note that it will have duplicate values, which is fine for this case. Next let's count our values using the PHP function [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) which will give us the results:

```
Array
(
    [7011 Trondheim] => 3
    [7048 Trondheim] => 2
    [7022 Trondheim] => 2
)
```

Now we have a unique array which also has a count of duplicates!

**NOTE**

I'm not familiar with ACF but I imagine we could do something like this to achieve what we're trying to do - also not tested:

```
<?php
    $addresses = array();
    if( have_posts() ) {
        while( have_posts() ){
            the_post();
            $city = get_field( 'poststed' );
            $zip = get_field( 'postnummer' );
            if( ! empty( $city ) && ! empty( $zip ) )
                $address[] = "{$zip} - {$city}";
        }
    }

    if( ! empty( $addresses ) ) {
        $uniqueAddresses = array_count_values( $addresses );
    }

    rewind_posts(); // Incase needed later.

if( ! empty( $uniqueAddresses ) ) : ?>

    <h3>Filter etter postnr:</h3>
    <ul>

<?php foreach( $uniqueAddresses as $address => $count ) : // Let's loop through our array 
        // Let's split our unique address back in to `poststed` and `postnummer`
        // $addressArr[0] => postnummer
        // $addressArr[1] => poststed
        $addressArr = explode( ' - ', $address );
?>

        <li><a href="?postnr=<?php echo $addressArr[0]; ?>"><?php echo "{$address}({$count})"; ?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Didn´t really work probarly

Comment: Didn't work how? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Sorry for the short response.

It looped out duplicates like the original loop, but did some sort of count - though not a correct one. :)

Like this.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnopqg9zlpcvsiy/Screenshot%202014-11-11%2018.39.46.png?dl=0

note: poststed = The city name, postnr = the zipcode varies

Comment: @ViralMediaWeb Try that new code block. This time I'm not looping through the actual posts the 2nd time, but the unique array itself.

Comment: " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ..."

ref to this line :
<?php foreach( $uniqueAddresses as $address => $count ) : // Let's loop through our array 
        // Let's split our unique address back in to `poststed` and `postnummer`
        // $addressArr[0] => postnummer
        // $addressArr[1] => poststed
        $addressArr = explode( ' - ', $address );
?>

Comment: @ViralMediaWeb and the two field names you're trying to get are `postnummer` and `poststed` correct? Are these saved as string? The only reason the foreach would error out if is it was empty, I've added an extra conditional to test if the `$uniqueAddresses` array is empty.

Comment: A print_r returns atleast one:
Array ( [0] => 7033 - Trondheim [1] => 7033 - Trondheim )

If I understand you correctly:
The zipcode (postnr) is a field-type: Number and the poststed is text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18568/discussion-between-howdy-mcgee-and-viralmediaweb).